# Defining a MX::Declare method as a attribute trigger

Tags: perl, methods, moose

The following code works as I'd expect. The cached lazy attribute gets cleared and rebuilt when the foo attribute it depends on is changed.

```
use MooseX::Declare;
use 5.010;

class Test {
  has foo => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'rw', trigger => sub {my $self = shift; $self->clearer}, default => '' );

  has lazy => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'ro', lazy => 1, clearer => 'clearer',
                default => method { say 'building lazy'; return "foo is '".$self->foo."'"; },
              );

  method say ( ) {
    say $self->lazy;
  }
}

my $inst = Test->new( foo => 'baz' );
$inst->say;
$inst->say;
say $inst->foo();
$inst->foo('bar'); 
$inst->say;
```

output:

```
building lazy
foo is 'baz'
foo is 'baz'
baz
building lazy
foo is 'bar'
```

How do I, however, use the MX::Declare sugar for the trigger subroutine? Defining foo as:

```
has foo => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'rw', trigger => method {$self->clearer}, default => '' );
```

Results in the class dying on compilation (below). Am I doing something wrong with my anonymous method declaration?

> Trigger must be a CODE ref on attribute (foo) at
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 423
>           Moose::Meta::Attribute::_process_trigger_option('Moose::Meta::Attribute',
>   'foo', 'HASH(0x2a5d14c)') called at C:
>   /Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 299
>           Moose::Meta::Attribute::_process_options('Moose::Meta::Attribute',
>   'foo', 'HASH(0x2a5d14c)') called at C:/Strawb
>   erry/perl/site/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 88
>           Moose::Meta::Attribute::new('Moose::Meta::Attribute', 'foo', 'trigger', 'MooseX::Method::Signatures::Meta::Metho
>   d=HASH(0x39a421c)', 'isa', 'Str', 'definition_context',
>   'HASH(0x3452184)', 'default', '', 'is', 'rw') called at C:/Straw
>   berry/perl/site/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 114
>           Moose::Meta::Attribute::interpolate_class_and_new('Moose::Meta::Attribute',
>   'foo', 'trigger', 'MooseX::Method::S
>   ignatures::Meta::Method=HASH(0x39a421c)', 'isa', 'Str', 'default', '',
>   'definition_context', 'HASH(0x3452184)', 'is', 'r w') called at
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Moose/Meta/Class.pm line 704
>           Moose::Meta::Class::_process_new_attribute('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x38c79d4)',
>   'foo', 'trigger', 'MooseX::Meth
>   od::Signatures::Meta::Method=HASH(0x39a421c)', 'isa', 'Str',
>   'default', '', 'definition_context', 'HASH(0x3452184)', 'is ', 'rw')
>   called at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Moose/Meta/Class.pm line 697
>           Moose::Meta::Class::_process_attribute('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x38c79d4)',
>   'foo', 'trigger', 'MooseX::Method::
>   Signatures::Meta::Method=HASH(0x39a421c)', 'isa', 'Str', 'default',
>   '', 'definition_context', 'HASH(0x3452184)', 'is', ' rw') called at
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Moose/Meta/Class.pm line 566
>           Moose::Meta::Class::add_attribute('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x38c79d4)',
>   'foo', 'trigger', 'MooseX::Method::Signa
>   tures::Meta::Method=HASH(0x39a421c)', 'isa', 'Str', 'default', '',
>   'definition_context', 'HASH(0x3452184)', 'is', 'rw') called at
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Moose.pm line 77
>           Moose::has('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x38c79d4)', 'foo', 'isa', 'Str', 'is', 'rw', 'trigger', 'MooseX::Method::Si
>   gnatures::Meta::Method=HASH(0x39a421c)', 'default', '') called at
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Moose/Exporter.pm line 356
>
> ```
>     Moose::has('foo', 'isa', 'Str', 'is', 'rw', 'trigger', 'MooseX::Method::Signatures::Meta::Method=HASH(0x39a421c) ',
> ```
>
> 'default', '') called at mx_declare.pl line 5
>           main::**ANON**() called at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/MooseX/Declare/Syntax/MooseSetup.pm line
>   81
>           MooseX::Declare::Syntax::MooseSetup::**ANON**('CODE(0x38c3a94)')
>   called at mx_declare.pl line 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `method` keyword returns an instance of the `MooseX::Method::Signatures::Meta::Method` class, which is a subclass of `Moose::Meta::Method`, which is a subclass of `Class::MOP::Method`.

Moose allows a method object for `default`, but not for `trigger`, which must be a regular coderef.

If you really want to use the `method` keyword there, you could probably do:

```
trigger => method { $self->clearer }->body,
```

But it's probably easier (and saner) to do what @cjm suggests and just use a regular coderef:

```
trigger => sub { shift->clearer },
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured it'd be something like that. I was interested more for consistencies' sake than anything else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  `method` returns an object, not a plain coderef.  However, you can write this even more concisely than `method` would allow:

```
has foo => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'rw', trigger => sub {shift->clearer}, default => '' );
```

That's 3 characters shorter than `method {$self->clearer}`.  And it has less overhead.